# Html5 video streaming server requirement

Tags: html, video, server, video-streaming

I'm developing a streaming website in html5 using the html5 video tag and I'm wondering what kind of server I need to support 100 simultaneous and different video stream at 4Mbsp as rate per second.
Also what kind of hdd or raid or whatelse I need to accomplish this.
I also need to keep in mind, that the system need to be scalable.
I saw AWS but it seem expensive ...
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Sorry, but hardware recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: `"I saw AWS but it seem expensive"` - Then try any of their competitors.  Any cloud solution is likely going to be orders of magnitude cheaper than building your own infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

The heavy lifting in a video streaming scenario is usually done by a CDN, which is heavily optimized for this role.   You want to buy this service, not build it; David is absolutely correct that building, optimizing, and maintaining your own infrastructure would be prohibitively expensive.  CDNs put massive resources into engineering solutions to the problem of delivering a high volume of data quickly to disparate locations.  Bottom line: if you're balking at the cost of Amazon's services, you cannot afford to engineer your own performant edge/origin architecture.

Some big name CDNs include Akamai, Amazon Cloudfront, Level3, BitGravity, Edgecast, and LimeLight.  Try reaching out to their Sales departments and see if anyone is willing to make you a good deal.

Comment: I don't understand: if i consider a streaming speed of 4Mbps X 100 users(simultaneously) I reach 400 Mbps that are 50 Mb x second and with a ssd hdd and 1Gbps bandwidth should I reach my goal or there are some other issue to consider ??

Comment: Yes.  For example, what happens when someone from the other side of the world visits?  Is the content served from the location where it was originally stored.  A CDN has an edge/origin (sort of like, delivery/storage) architecture that allows them to deliver the files from a different location than from where it was originally stored.

Comment: Also caching.  What happens when two people from the same geographical location -- say, India -- view the video twice?  Do the bits have to be shipped across the ocean each time, or can the expensive long haul be performed only once for the first person who requests, and let subsequent viewers view from a more local point of presence?

Comment: The point is that there is a great deal of engineering involved in making sure the bits are (for the most part) available a very short time after they're requested no matter where on the globe the request comes from.  The infrastructure required to make things magically "just work" is very expensive and difficult to build and maintain.  Unless you want this to be your business, you're best off just buying this service from someone who has put down the time, money, engineering, and human networking required for such an undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to play and video in ios

```
<?
$file="abc.mp4";
@fread($file);
$file = $play;
$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');



$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;

    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);


$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}

fclose($fp);
exit();


}
?>
```